# Creating a 2D List To Store Tkinter Buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Trying to create a method that creates 64 buttons. This method will append the buttons to a two dimensional list and put them on the tkinter canvas using .grid(). Not exactly sure what the problem is. When running the code it does literally nothing, no error, no code 0 not even the tkinter window appears. The method is below with the rest of its class. I also posted the master class, anything helps.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk

# Fonts used throughout the class

LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 14)
SMALL_FONT = ("Verdana", 10)

# Game Board

board = [['r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r'],
         ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
         ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
         ['R', 'N', 'B', 'K', 'Q', 'B', 'N', 'R']
         ]


class Board(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # init variables
        self.turn = True
        self.buttons = []
        self.board = board

        # Header
        label = Tk.Label(self, text="Chess", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        # Game
        # Sets game board
        self.set_buttons()

        # Sets game board
        # self.set_buttons2()

        back_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Main Menu", command=self.main_menu(controller))
        back_button.pack(side=Tk.BOTTOM, fill=Tk.BOTH)

    # Stores buttons in list for later use
    # Places buttons on canvas.
    def set_buttons(self):
        for i in range(8):
            self.buttons.append([])
            for j in range(8):
                self.buttons[i].append(ttk.Button(self, text=self.board[i][j]))
                self.buttons[i][j].configure(command=self.piece_control)
                self.buttons[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")

    def piece_control(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def main_menu(controller):
        from MainMenu import MainMenu
        return lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu)
```

I will also add the master class just in case that is where the problem is.

```
from MainMenu import MainMenu
from Board import Board
from Rules import Rules
from Options import Options
import Tkinter as Tk


class Main(Tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    Tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        Tk.Tk.title(self, "Chess")

        container = Tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainMenu, Board, Options, Rules):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainMenu)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

# Creates Object of main and loops it.

Application = Main()
Application.geometry("650x650")
Application.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say the code "does nothing", do you mean the buttons are not created, or that clicking on them doesn't work? If the latter, what does `self.piece_control` do? Does it expect to get an argument, such as the `i` value you're setting as a default in your `lambda` (which is good code, working around the issues with creating closures in a loop, but pointless since you don't use `i` later).

Comment: Print self.buttons to make sure it is what you want, using a smaller number, anything greater than 8 so you have 2+ rows.  Can't say more without knowing how you instantiate Tk().

Comment: I just saw *"and put them on the tkinter canvas using .grid()"*.  You have to put them in a frame using grid() and use canvas.create_window to put the frame in the canvas widget http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm  canvas.create_window(100, 200, window=frm, anchor=tk.CENTER)

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry should've clarified a bit more, when I compile and run the application, the window does not appear, its like it never reaches the mainloop() method call. This only happens when the set_buttons method is called. And as of now the command does nothing, just a pass statement, so yea the lambda was silly.

Answer (score 0):

it works great for me, it does create an 8x8 matrix on the root.

```
import ttk
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
buttons = []

def set_buttons():
    for i in range(8):
        buttons.append([])
        for j in range(8):[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            buttons[i].append(ttk.Button(text='3'))
            buttons[i][j].configure(command=com)
            buttons[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew")

def com():
    print 3

set_buttons()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: 8x8 matrix]
if you're still having problems then its probably because of other parts in your code, so please post a more extensive code block for us to find the problem.

Comment: I am going to try to add more code up so you guys can get a better visual but there are so many other classes its hard to pick out what might be the problem. And I am glad its at least working for someone. Please take note the bug only occurs when the method is called.

Answer (score 0):

After further debugging apparently using .pack() with .grid() was proving to be quite chaotic. Made a few simple changes to the init function by changing the .pack() methods to .grid() and it works like a charm.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):

    Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    # init variables
    self.turn = True
    self.buttons = []
    self.board = board

    # Header
    label = Tk.Label(self, text="Chess", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

    # Game
    # Sets game board
    self.set_buttons()

    back_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Main Menu", command=self.main_menu(controller))
    back_button.grid(row=8, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
```